# SpringBoot & Spring MVC - How to turn a flash attribute into a permanent attribute

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, modelattribute

I am using Spring MVC for my Web Application and I need to turn a flash attribute into a permanent atribute so that if the user reloads the page it doesnt expire.

My controller looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/verResultados/{id}")
public String irAVerResultados(@PathVariable Long id, RedirectAttributes redir)
{
    redir.addFlashAttribute("encuestaSeleccionada", encuestasRepository.findOne(id));
    return "redirect:/verResultados";
}
@RequestMapping(value="verResultados")
public String verResultados(@ModelAttribute("encuestaSeleccionada") Encuesta encuesta, Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("encuestaSeleccionada", encuesta); // This doesnt work.
    return "verResultados";
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

model.addAttribute is like request.setAttribute, so it is a flash attribute. in order to make a data permanent, i think you should use session. bit dirty, though